# Accessing the C++ map elements with elements passed to a function is not printing exact values

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, visual-studio-2019, stdmap

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <map>
    #include <utility>

    using namespace std;

    const std::string& foo(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a) {
    // const string& foo(const std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& a) { // *First fix*
         const std::string& strfoo = a.first;
         return strfoo;
    }

    int main() {
        std::map<std::string, std::string> m1;

        m1.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(std::string("John"),std::string("Doe")));

        std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator k = m1.begin();

        //std::pair<std::string, std::string> p1 = make_pair(k->first,k->second); // *Second Fix*

        const std::string& f = foo(*k);

        std::cout <<  "Hello " << f << " Bye";

        return 0;
     }
```

If I run this code (without uncommenting anything. I am using Visual Studio), I get the output as
Hello  Bye

Now I have added 2 comments in the code labelled as first fix and the second fix respectively.

Both of these so called fixes are printing the output as
Hello John Bye

1. First fix:
   If I comment the line

   ```
    const string& foo(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a) {
   ```

   and uncomment the first fix code which is making the first std::string as const, It prints the needed "Hello John Bye".
2. Second fix:
   If I keep everything intact, and uncomment the second fix where I am creating a copy of the element of the map. It prints the required "Hello John Bye" when passing the pair p1 instead of dereferencing the iterator.
3. Third fix:
   If I remove the reference &(ampersand) from the line

   ```
   const string& foo(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a) {
   ```

   OR

   ```
   const std::string& f = foo(*k);
   ```

   It also results in a copy and I get the output "Hello John Bye".

For the first one, it looks like since we are passing element of a map so we should keep the functions signature so that the key of the map should be const (I am still not sure why the code runs though)

Could someone elaborate how these fixes are working?

Comment: Your said **If I run this code (without uncommenting anything. I am using Visual Studio), I get the output as Hello Bye**. The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/2XIWbtLwe) for the code that you posted(without any fixed or modifications) is `Hello John Bye` but you said that your are getting the output `Hello Bye`. Did you make a typo(mistake) in writing the output?

Comment: @AnoopRana: without fix, code exhibit UB, so your output is also possible.

Comment: I am running this on Visual Studio 2019. I am getting the output as
        Hello  Bye

Which compiler are you trying?

Comment: @AnoopRana: I just saw the output which you showed. Not sure if it may be a bug in MSVC. I tried this with gcc and I was getting a garbage string instead of nothing. Not sure why there is a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

map's value type is indeed `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` and not `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`, but the latter can be converted in the former.

Applying `foo` on temporary returns pointer which becomes dangling at end of full expression.

1.

Changing `foo` signature to take exact value type avoid the creation of the problematic temporary.

2. ```
   std::pair<std::string, std::string> p1 = make_pair(k->first,k->second);
   const std::string& f = foo(p1);
   ```

You no longer have temporary neither.

3. ```
   string foo(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a);

   const std::string& f = foo(*k);
   ```

You no longer return reference, but a temporary.
That temporary has its life extended by the bounding to const reference `f`.

> `std::string f = foo(*k);`

reference return by `foo` is used to construct `f` before becoming dangling.
so your are ok too.

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1: Without any fixes/modifications

**First** note that for a map `std::map<K,V>`, `std::map<K, V>::value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`.

**Second** **dereferencing** an iterator from a `std::map<K, V>` will give you a `std::pair<const K, V>&`.

Now lets apply the above two facts to your example. In particular, the expression `*k` gives us

```
std::pair<const std::string, std::string>&
```

**Next**, the function `foo` in this case takes a

```
const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a
```

Note that here the `std::pair` itself is `const`. So this means, its members are also const since the members of a `const` object are itself(themselves) `const`.

Also, this function `foo` returns a **reference to const string**. So you should get `Hello John Bye` as output instead of `Hello Bye`. My guess is that this is a **bug** in MSVC since in gcc and clang you get the expected(`Hello John Bye`) as output.

##### Case 2: With first fix

In this first fix, you have change your function parameter to be

```
const std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& a
```

In the above statement, you have explicitly set the `first` member of the `std::pair` as `const` which again should give the output `Hello John Bye`. In the previous case(CASE 1), the `first` member was **implicitly** `const`. So Case 1 and Case 2 are not really so different except that in Case 1 the `second` member of the passed pair is also `const`. You can verify this by trying to change the `second` member by adding  the following inside `foo`'s body in Case 1

```
//std::string &secondStr = a.second; //this won't work in CASE 1 because second member is implicitly const in Case 1
const std::string &secondStr = a.second; //this will work in CASE 1
```

##### Case 3: With second fix

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> p1 = make_pair(k->first,k->second);
const std::string& f = foo(p1);
```

This time you're passing the `std::pair`, `p1` that you created using `make_pair`. Again, just like Case 1, here the **parameter** of the function `foo` is `const` so the `first` and `second` members of the parameterwill be **implicitly `const`** and the output should be `Hello John Buy`.

##### Case 4: With third fix

```
string foo(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& a);

const std::string& f = foo(*k); //f extends the lifetime of the temporary returned by foo
```

In this case, there is **no change** in the function parameter but now we're returning the string **by value**. Here, `f` extends the lifetime of the temporary returned by the call to `foo` and the output should be the same as before(`Hello John Bye`).

##### Summary

The output `Hello Bye` that you're getting in the very first case seems to be a **bug** in MSVC to me.